# Click on a Surface selects the wrong Surface

Tags: famo.us, surface

With a for loop I create 10 different Surfaces. By clicking on one of them, I want to get the content of this surface. But that s not working. instead I always get the content of the last created Surface (in my case it is 9). What do I have to change to get the content of the selected (clicked) surface and not the content of the last created?

here is my Code:

```js
for (f = 0; f < 10; f++) {
        var draggable = new Draggable({
            xRange: [0, 1000],
            yRange: [0, 1000]
        });

        var surface = new Surface({
            size: [true, true],
            content: f,
            properties:{
                fontSize:'16px',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                borderRadius:'50px',
                backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0',
                border:'solid'
            }
        });

        surface.on("click",function(){alert(surface.content)});

        surface.pipe(draggable);        
        mainContext.add(draggable).add(surface);
  }
```

Comment: wrapping the creation of the surface and the event handler inside a function and calling the function will also fix this. But you should plus / check talves answer since it's right.

Comment: I should do an example also of the correct way to call a function binding it to the surface to show a better practice.

Comment: yes, that would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct Surface is being selected. The issue is in the reference of the `surface.content` of the click function.  The surface reference has been replaced each time until the last surface remains. Reference the current surface clicked using `this.content` in the function because `this` is bound to the current clicked surface in the click function.

**[Example code Here](http://jsbin.com/coxiji/1/edit?js,output)**

```js
for (f = 0; f < 10; f++) {
    var draggable = new Draggable({
        xRange: [0, 1000],
        yRange: [0, 1000]
    });

    var surface = new Surface({
        size: [true, true],
        content: f,
        properties: {
            fontSize: '16px',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            borderRadius: '50px',
            backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0',
            border: 'solid'
        }
    });

    surface.on("click", function () {
        alert(this.content)
    });

    surface.pipe(draggable);
    mainContext.add(draggable).add(surface);
}
```

Comment: Manual hoisting by moving variable declarations outside `for` loop will remove ambiguity regarding block level scope. Just a note.

Comment: You can see my comment above that I mention showing the best practices example, but this gives him the quick fix explanation for now. Thanks for the comment reminder.